# How can I open a print dialog without a second window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I would like to give the user the opportunity to print out part of my page. Currently I do this by opening a new window and executing window.print(). Since Chrome was updated to version 90, the page hangs when you click the X button. Can you help me fix it?

Code Example:

```
var html = "<html>";
html += "<head><title>Druckvorschau</title></head>"
html += "<h1>Example</h1>"
html += "</html>";
var width = 600;
var height = 800;
var left = screen.width - 600;
var top = screen.height - 800;
var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
var printWin = window.open('', 'blank', params);
printWin.title = "Druckvorschau";
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
printWin.focus();
printWin.print();
```

[image: Print-Window]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iframe instead of a new window and then print the iframe:

```js
var html = "<html>";
html += "<head><title>Druckvorschau</title></head>"
html += "<h1>Example</h1>"
html += "</html>";

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
var printWin = iframe.contentWindow;

printWin.title = "Druckvorschau";
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
printWin.focus();
printWin.print();

// And then delete it afterward:
document.body.removeChild(iframe)
```